# backtick operator not working for executing php script from perl

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to call php script from perl. After googling i found i can use backtick operator for this.

but when i tried

```
my $phpOutput = `https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=<mykey>&mobiles=<mobile>&message=Thank%20you%20for%20placing%20order%20at%20WokoShop.%20Order%20id%3A%201434%20Invoice%20Value%3A%201445.04&sender=WOKOSP&route=4`;
```

It is not working. The same url i tried in browser that works fine.

What changes i need to do to make it work in perl script also.

I am using this perl package.

```
use LWP::Simple;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to retrieve result of arbitrary HTTP request, because with URL and LWP module this doesn't looks like calls at all. Clarify your question - right now it is unclear what you really want.

Comment: "After googling i found i can use backtick operator for this" - I would be very interested to see the page which gave you this impression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of your backticks aren't a shell command, they're a URL. Since you're already using `LWP::Simple` you can retrieve the value at this url with a call to `get`

It looks like this, although the value presumably isn't representative of what you expect as you will need to replace `<mykey>` and `<mobile>` by their real values. You don't *have* to build the URL using the [`URI`](http://metacpan.org/module/URI) module like this, but it makes it much simpler to alter individual query parameters and avoids you having to deal with URI-escaped strings

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use URI;
use LWP::Simple 'get';

my $url = URI->new('https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php');
$url->query_form(
    authkey => '<mykey>',
    mobiles => '<mobile>',
    message => 'Thank you for placing order at WokoShop. Order id: 1434 Invoice Value: 1445.04',
    sender  => 'WOKOSP',
    route   => 4,
);

say get $url;
```

#### output

```
366141754843343731333535
```

Answer (score -3):

To call a specific URL/page in UNIX you can use ***curl***, so instead of typing the URL as is in the backticks, you do it as such:

```
my $phpOutput = `curl 'https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=<mykey>&mobiles=<mobile>&message=Thank%20you%20for%20placing%20order%20at%20WokoShop.%20Order%20id%3A%201434%20Invoice%20Value%3A%201445.04&sender=WOKOSP&route=4'`;
```

You can also do:

```
my $phpOutput = qx|curl 'https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=<mykey>&mobiles=<mobile>&message=Thank%20you%20for%20placing%20order%20at%20WokoShop.%20Order%20id%3A%201434%20Invoice%20Value%3A%201445.04&sender=WOKOSP&route=4'|;
```

Comment: *"Using `LWP::Simple` ... offers you a plenty of features to control the HTTP request you're sending, by setting the request headers, parameters, etc. I don't prefer using this option for simple URL calls similar to your case."*

I assume you meant *“don't prefer”*? It's fine, but rather unusual. I would write “I don't recommend”.

This isn't true, and you're probably thinking of [LWP](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP). [LWP::Simple](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Simple) offers only the very basic calls `get`, `head`, and variations on `get`; there is no way to affect the headers it sends

Comment: I would also say that Perl's capabilities are way beyond those of `curl` or `wget`. Your `my $phpOutput = \`curl $url\`` is identical to  `my $phpOutput = get $url` and also avoids starting shell and curl processes.

Comment: Your alternative `my $phpOutput = system( "curl '$url'")` will discard the contents of the web page and return only the status of the `curl` command to `$phpOutput`, while `my $phpOutput = exec "curl '$url'"` will *kill* the Perl process if it is successful, and return a status code in `$phpOutput` if the `fork` fails

Comment: The only viable solutions are your first and second statements, which are equivalent apart from the alternative quoting. And, as I said, `LWP::Simple` is a better alternative to those

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I'm not the Perl expert and I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I just tried to share my knowledge, which wasn't accurate, and benefit from the experts' comments.